# Linux: Is writeback related to number of files?

Tags: c++, linux

I am trying to do some experiments of pagecache and writeback mechanism on linux 5.4.81. I have set dirty_ratio to be 50, dirty_background_ratio 45, dirty_expire_centisecs 500000000, dirty_writeback_centisecs 500000000. When I write a big file of 250GB using write(), I can find that writeback begin to work when dirty_pages reach 45% of total memory, which is in line with expectation.

But when I write 125 small files of 2GB, the writeback begin to work when dirty_pages only reach about 25%. I wonder why this happen?

The total memory of my platform is 256G.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  struct timeval start, end;
  long long total_time = 0;
  ofstream outfile("write_time.txt",ios::trunc);
  int loop=1;
  while(loop--){
    for(int i=0; i<125; i++){
      stringstream ss;
      string num;
      ss<<i;
      ss>>num;
      string a = "test";
      string b = ".dat";
      string fileName = a+num+b;
      const char*tmp=fileName.c_str();
      int fp = open(tmp,O_CREAT|O_RDWR,S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
      // int fp = open(tmp,O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC);
      int pos = 0;
      char data[1024] = "ab\n";
      gettimeofday( &start, NULL );
      while (1)
        {
          write(fp, data, 1024);
          pos++;
          if (pos >= 2*1024*1024)
            break;
        }
      gettimeofday( &end, NULL );
      int timeuse = 1000000 * ( end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec ) + end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec;
      printf("write_time: %d us\n", timeuse);
      total_time +=timeuse;
      outfile<<timeuse<<endl;
    }
  }
  outfile<<total_time;
  outfile.close();
  return 0;
}
```